# Store a very large numpy.ndarray into cells of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am doing some operations which give a `numpy.ndarray` as output. I wish to store that array into columns of a Pandas dataframe.

I am currently doing so by:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(index=df['id'], columns=df['id'])
A_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(df)

sim1 = cosine_similarity(A_sparse[0:5000],A_sparse)
print(sim1) #upto this point the code runs fine even for larger datasets

df_new[0:5000] = sim1[:, :] #this statement crashes everytime for 5000 rows

sim1 = cosine_similarity(A_sparse[5000:10000],A_sparse)
df_new[5000:10000] = sim1[:, :]
```

Though the above code runs absolutely well for  small arrays but crashes for larger ones `(5000,28785)`.

Sample data for reference:

`df.head(5)`:

```
            Qua  F  M  0  35  5  E \
id                                                                    
11391                       1  0  1     0      0     1                    1   
28400                       1  1  0     0      1     0                    0   
30268                       3  1  0     0      1     0                    0   
31604                       3  1  0     0      1     0                    0   
32885                       2  1  0     1      0     0                    0   

        Ea  Ir N HR \
id                                                               
11391                          0        0              0             0   
28400                          0        0              0             0   
30268                          0        0              0             0   
31604                          0        0              0             0   
32885                          0        0              0             0   

        No Sc  So  Sou  \
id                                                                    
11391                          0         0                  0             0   
28400                          0         1                  0             0   
30268                          1         0                  0             0   
31604                          0         0                  1             0   
32885                          0         0                  0             0   

        SA  Wa  WM  YR  
id                                                                  
11391                       0      0                     0                 0  
28400                       0      0                     0                 0  
30268                       0      0                     0                 0  
31604                       0      0                     0                 0  
32885                       0      0                     1                 0
```

`A_sparse`:

```
(0, 0)  1
(0, 2)  1
(0, 5)  1
(0, 6)  1
(1, 0)  1
(1, 1)  1
(1, 4)  1
(1, 12) 1
(2, 0)  3
(2, 1)  1
(2, 4)  1
(2, 11) 1
(3, 0)  3
(3, 1)  1
(3, 4)  1
(3, 13) 1
```

`sim1`:

```
`[1.0, 0.25, 0.43301270189221935, 0.43301270189221935, 0.3779644730092272, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.75, 0.3779644730092272, 0.25, 0.3779644730092272, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.5669467095138407, 0.7216878364870323, 0.43301270189221935, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5, 0.5669467095138407, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5669467095138407, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.3779644730092272, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5669467095138407, 0.5669467095138407, 0.43301270189221935, 0.43301270189221935, 0.7559289460184544, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.75, 0.25, 0.43301270189221935, 0.3779644730092272, 0.7216878364870323, 0.7216878364870323, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.7216878364870323, 0.5669467095138407, 0.75, 0.3779644730092272, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5669467095138407, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5, 0.3779644730092272, 0.43301270189221935, 1.0, 0.43301270189221935, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.25, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5669467095138407, 0.3779644730092272, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5669467095138407, 0.5669467095138407, 0.5669467095138407, 0.5669467095138407, 0.25, 0.75, 0.25, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.43301270189221935, 0.43301270189221935, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.7216878364870323, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5669467095138407, 0.7559289460184544, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.7559289460184544, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.3779644730092272, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.75, 0.5773502691896258, 0.3779644730092272, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5, 0.5669467095138407, 0.5669467095138407, 0.7216878364870323, 0.5, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5, 0.5669467095138407, 0.3779644730092272, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.3779644730092272, 0.43301270189221935, 0.43301270189221935, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5669467095138407, 0.7216878364870323, 0.7559289460184544, 0.5669467095138407, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5669467095138407, 0.7559289460184544, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5, 0.43301270189221935, 0.75, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5, 0.25, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.7216878364870323, 0.75, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.25, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.43301270189221935, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5773502691896258, 0.3779644730092272, 0.43301270189221935, 0.3779644730092272, 0.5669467095138407, 0.3779644730092272, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5669467095138407, 0.3779644730092272, 0.3779644730092272, 0.3779644730092272, 0.3779644730092272, 0.25, 0.3779644730092272, 0.5669467095138407, 0.43301270189221935, 0.43301270189221935, 0.7559289460184544, 0.3779644730092272, 0.43301270189221935, 0.5, 0.377964473009227]`
```

Comment: What about just `df_new = pd.DataFrame(sim1,index=df_new.index, columns=df_new.columns)`?

Comment: You should add some code to generate example data, as it is, it's not very clear what your data is like.

Comment: Since you seem to be using sparse data, have you tried sparse data structures in Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html ?

Comment: Converting large sparse matrices to dense ones can produce memory errors.  Could you demonstrate with a small case, showing `df`, `A_sparse`, `sim1` and `df_new`.  I don't want to guess as what is happening (and I don't want to try to recreate your case from the scanty information you provide).

Comment: @cs95 kindly review my updated question. I need to do this processing multiple times...

Comment: @suvayu I have added sample data kindly review the question again

Comment: @Prasanth I don't think sparse data structure could help me here

Comment: @hpaulj I have added sample data, kindly review the question again.